# Laravel File storage with Imagick

Tags: php, laravel, imagick

I'm trying to download a multi-page PDF, convert it to separate JPG images and store them using local Laravel storage disk.

My problem, is that for some reason only the last image is saved correctly, all other created image files seem to be corrupted.

My code:

```
$imgExt = new Imagick();
$imgExt->setResolution(300, 300);
$imgExt->readImageBlob( // Reading PDF blob
    Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])
        ->get($pdfURL)->body() // Getting PDF from URL
);

$imgExt->setImageFormat('jpg');
$imgExt->setImageCompressionQuality(70);

foreach ($imgExt as $key => $image) {
    $response = Storage::disk('mis_storage_local')
        ->put("./$randomFileName", // unique file name
            (string)$image);

}
```

Note: Imagick::writeImages **does work correctly** and saves images without any problem, but I want to use Laravel File storage instead of directly saving to a directory using Imagick::writeImages.

I don't get any errors or exceptions.

Using Laravel 9, Imagick 3.7.0 with removed PDF restriction from *policy.xml*

Comment: Have you checked `foreach ($imgExt as $key => $image)` returns value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$imgExt = new Imagick();
$imgExt->setResolution(300, 300);
$imgExt->readImageBlob( // Reading PDF blob
    Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])
        ->get($pdfURL)->body() // Getting PDF from URL
);

$imgExt->setImageFormat('jpg');
$imgExt->setImageCompressionQuality(70);

$imgExt->writeImage('mis_storage_local/'.$randomFileName.'.jpg');
```